# How Firebase Custom audience > Dimension > automatic pick country id

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I want to know, when you try to create custom audience in firebase it gives you some of its automatic created audiences. Can anyone please tell me how firebase pick this location .The tag name is(Country Id) but after sometimes it gives the wrong country name.
when i try to push notification to my client in USA selected audiences it also sends notifications to Canada's client who travelled from USA to CANADA.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, "Analytics derives location data from users' IP addresses."

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486

Comment: Thank bro for helping.